# nuxt.js no static folder on build

Tags: nuxt.js

i follow nuxt guidelines, putting some images, logos and icons in static folder.

- on run dev, all is fine, images are mapped.
- Then i run build, deploy package.json, nuxtconfig and the .nuxt folder to my vps.
- When i visit my production website, all static images are 404.
- Looking at the dir, there is no static folder. Looking at the generated source, for example the logo source expected is http://mywebsite.com/logo.png (404 is logical as the file is missing)
- So i try to put logo.png at the root, but http://mywebsite.com/logo.png generate a 404 error. I also try to put logon.png in other directories as .nuxt/views, and son on, same effect)

Hum, i certainly missunderstood something, but what :-)

Using nuxt2, nothing about static folder in my nuxt.config

PS. 404 on http://mywebsite.com/logo.png is the nuxt generated one

Thanks. Zoé

Comment: what mode are using? Ssr? spa? generate?

Comment: oh yes sorry, no mode, so ssr by default

Comment: So you start your app with nuxt start right? Then you need also deploy your static folder

Comment: thanks a lot @Aldarund Deploy static folder at the root seems to resolved my problem. I need to test all site but first try is ok, static logo is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to deploy your static folder from sources too. It is not bundled into .nuxt

Comment: Sorry, but could you tell me, what you mean exactly by bundle into .nuxt? And is it still necessary? My static folder is missing, too